# "Cannot query field "available" on type "Query"

Tags: graphql

I get the error message "Cannot query field "available" on type "Query" when I try to fetch all products including the available property.

### Query call

```
const res = await fetch(`graphql?query={products{
    id
    name
    available
  }}`);
```

### Schema

```
export default `
type Product {
  id: ID!
  name: String! 
  available: [Available]
}

type Available  {
  stock: String
  size: String
}

input AvailableInput {
  stock: String
  size: String
}

type Query {
  product(name: String!): Product
  products: [Product] 
}

type Mutation {
  addProduct(name: String! available:[AvailableInput] ): Product
}
`;
```

Answer (score 1):

what does your `type Product` look like in Schema? perhaps you're missing a field on that as you're querying the `available` field as a subfield of `Product`

Comment: if you look at the schema part of the code you see there is a field of available there

Comment: yeah, now there is .. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `available` field returns object of `type Available`, so the first error is that you have no subfields in your query string.

Gives this a try:

```
const res = await fetch(`graphql?query={products{
    id
    name
    available {
        stock
        size
    }
  }}`);
```